# Stop the effect of calling an entry

Tags: cobol

I am trying to call an internal entry in cobol.
The call is OK, but the problem that there is some paragraphs after the entry that are also wrongly executed.

Here is my program:

```
   IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
   PROGRAM-ID. ENTR1POW.
   DATA DIVISION.
   WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
   LOCAL-STORAGE SECTION.
   PROCEDURE DIVISION.
    display "BEFORE CALL NOM_PROC1======================="
    PERFORM NOM_PROC1 THRU E--NOM_PROC1
    display "AFTER CALL NOM_PROC1======================="
    display "CALL NOM_PROC2============================="
    PERFORM NOM_PROC2 THRU E--NOM_PROC2
    display "CALL ENTRY1============================"
    CALL 'ENTRY1'
    GOBACK.

   NOM_PROC1.
       display "PGM ENTR1POW: BEGIN NOM_PROC1"
       display "PGM ENTR1POW:   END NOM_PROC1"
       CONTINUE.
   E--NOM_PROC1.
       EXIT.

   NOM_PROC2 SECTION.
       display "PGM ENTR1POW: BEGIN NOM_PROC2"

       ENTRY 'ENTRY1'
       display "===========BEGIN ENTRY ENTRY1"
       display "===========END   ENTRY ENTRY1"

       ENTRY 'ENTRY2'
       display "===========BEGIN ENTRY ENTRY2"
       display "===========END   ENTRY ENTRY2"

       ENTRY 'ENTRY3'
       display "===========BEGIN ENTRY ENTRY3"
       display "===========END   ENTRY ENTRY3"

       display "PGM ENTR1POW:   END NOM_PROC2"
       CONTINUE.
   E--NOM_PROC2.
       EXIT.

   NOM_PROC3 SECTION.
       display "PGM ENTR1POW: BEGIN NOM_PROC3"
       display "PGM ENTR1POW:   END NOM_PROC3"
       CONTINUE.
   E--NOM_PROC3 SECTION.
       EXIT.

   NOM_PROC4.
       display "PGM ENTR1POW: BEGIN NOM_PROC4"
       display "PGM ENTR1POW:   END NOM_PROC4"
       CONTINUE.
   E--NOM_PROC4.
       EXIT.
```

The output that i obtained is:

```
BEFORE CALL NOM_PROC1=======================
PGM ENTR1POW: BEGIN NOM_PROC1
PGM ENTR1POW:   END NOM_PROC1
AFTER CALL NOM_PROC1=======================
CALL NOM_PROC2=============================
PGM ENTR1POW: BEGIN NOM_PROC2
===========BEGIN ENTRY ENTRY1
===========END   ENTRY ENTRY1
===========BEGIN ENTRY ENTRY2
===========END   ENTRY ENTRY2
===========BEGIN ENTRY ENTRY3
===========END   ENTRY ENTRY3
PGM ENTR1POW:   END NOM_PROC2
CALL ENTRY1============================
===========BEGIN ENTRY ENTRY1
===========END   ENTRY ENTRY1
===========BEGIN ENTRY ENTRY2
===========END   ENTRY ENTRY2
===========BEGIN ENTRY ENTRY3
===========END   ENTRY ENTRY3
PGM ENTR1POW:   END NOM_PROC2
PGM ENTR1POW: BEGIN NOM_PROC3
PGM ENTR1POW:   END NOM_PROC3
PGM ENTR1POW: BEGIN NOM_PROC4
PGM ENTR1POW:   END NOM_PROC4
```

I think that the call to the paragraphs NOM_PROC3 and NOM_PROC4 shouldn't happen.

Comment: I kown that if i moved the paragraph NOM_PROC2 into the end of the program then my problem will be resolved, but i want to do that ? Is there any other way to resolve my problem.

Thank you in advnace for your reply.

Comment: What compiler are you using? The ENTRY is not intended to be in the program which CALLs it, it is supposed to be in another program. What are you trying to do? As @cschneid has said, a "contained" or "nested" program is probably more what you want. You'll also confuse yourself if you think a PERFORM is a CALL. It is not, so you messages are incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

First, think *hard* before you use `ENTRY`.  In 30 years of coding, I've encountered it once, in a program written in the early 1970s, and there it served no useful purpose.  Consider nested programs if you see a need for `ENTRY`.  @BrianTiffin makes a case for `ENTRY` in non-mainframe environments in the comments.

The `ENTRY` statement establishes an alternate entry point in your code. It's not like a `PERFORM`. You have to explicitly return from that alternate entry point just like you return from your main entry point.  This is typically done with a `GOBACK` statement.

Your program is behaving as it should.  You have no `GOBACK` after the `ENTRY 'ENTRY1'` statement so when you `CALL 'ENTRY1'` your code execution continues until it encounters end of program.

Comment: The reason that i use entries is just that i am trying to migrate a PL1 programs that contains entries and i try to conserve this aspect on my migrated programs.

Comment: Finally, i externalise the paragraph that contains the entries into a sub-program and it works for me.

Comment: I'd just like to add a second.  For GUI programming, `ENTRY` is a powerful thing.  It allows callbacks to have access to state in working-storage.  Comes in pretty handy for things like GTK+ button click handlers, and X11 events, etc.